# How to correctly bind React onClick event with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, jsx, sprockets

Basically there's no sign that the event is binded somewhere and it's not firing. Here's the Component

```
class AgendaPointsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onAgendaPointClick = this.props.onAgendaPointClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let items = this.props.agenda_points.map((a, i) => {
      return <AgendaPoint key={i} agenda_point={a} index={i} onClick={this.onAgendaPointClick} />
    })

    console.log(this.props)

    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {items}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    ); 
  }
}
```

The console.log(this.props) outputs:

```
Object
item_point: Object
item_points: Array[4]
onItemPointClick: onItemPointClick(id)
onModalCloseClick: onModalCloseClick(id)
store: Object
storeSubscription: Subscription
__proto__: Object
```

Here's the redux component:

```
const OPEN_AGENDA_POINT = 'meeting/OPEN_AGENDA_POINT'
const CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT = 'meeting/CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT'

const initialState = {
  modal_is_open: false,
  point_id: 0,
  point_data: {}
}

const openAgendaPoint = function (id) {
  return {
    type: OPEN_AGENDA_POINT,
    id: id
  }
}

const closeAgendaPoint = function (id) {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT,
    id: id
  }
}

const agendaPointsReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_AGENDA_POINT: {
      state.modal_is_open = true,
      point_id = action.id
    }
    case CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT: {
      state.modal_is_open = false
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}


const agendaPointsUiStateProps = (state) => {
  return {
    agenda_point: state.point_data
  }
}

const agendaPointsUiActions = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onAgendaPointClick: (id) => {
      console.log(id)
      dispatch(openAgendaPoint(id))
    },
    onModalCloseClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(closeAgendaPoint(id))
    }
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(
  agendaPointsReducer, 
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)

// Usage:
const AgendaPointsList = connectWithStore(
  store, 
  AgendaPointsList, 
  agendaPointsUiStateProps, 
  agendaPointsUiActions
)
```

That's the child component:

```
class AgendaPoint extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{ this.props.index + 1 }</td>
        <td>{ this.props.agenda_point.title}</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>{ this.props.agenda_point.agenda_time } min</td>
      </tr>
    ); 
  }
}
```

I tried multiple ways of binding the event:

```
onClick={this.props.onAgendaPointClick.bind(a.id, this)
onClick={this.props.onAgendaPointClick(a.id, this).bind(this)
onClick={() => this.props.onAgendaPointClick(a.id))
```

Non seem to work.

Using [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/390) for reac-redux connect wrapper to pass in store. This is running  on Ruby on Rails Sprockets beta4.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: correct binding would be `onClick={this.props.onItemClick.bind(this, a.id)`

Comment: this should work:

`onClick={() => this.props.onItemClick(a.id))}`

There is no use in binding it to _this_ in this case.
What kind of error do you get when you use this approach?

Comment: @cubbuk it works to the extent that React debugging tools now recognize as `onClick="bound onItemClick()"` .. but nothing happens and console log in the event itself doesn't do a thing

Comment: @stevenmahieu absolutely nothing, not bound, no event no nothing. just "onClick=onClick()" in React dev tools.

Comment: @Aurimas is the function _onItemClick_ present in your _this.props_?

Comment: @Aurimas try it like this onClick={(() => {this.props.onItemClick(a.id)}).bind(this)}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136612/discussion-between-aurimas-and-steven-mahieu).

Comment: After some chatting we're still unable to find the solution. The event listener is not registered on the required dom elements (if it should be). Anyone has an idea?

Comment: is component `Item` in your `this.props.agenda_points.map` the `ItemPoint` class declaration in the last part?

Comment: No. sorry, I was trying to make the code more general so I had changed the names, now put the actual code. For me it seems, like React is not doing part of the job and not binding the event actually, what could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the on click to be on you  tag.
With the following code change you event will be triggerd:

```
class AgendaPoint extends React.Component {   render() {
    return (
      <tr onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <td>{ this.props.index + 1 }</td>
        <td>{ this.props.agenda_point.title}</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>{ this.props.agenda_point.agenda_time } min</td>
      </tr>
    );    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the event in your ItemList constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onItemClick = this.onItemClick.bind(this);
  }
```

Then in your ItemList render function ...

```
  let items = this.props.agenda_points.map((a, i) => {
    return <Item key={i} agenda_point={a} index={i} onClick={this.props.onItemClick} />
  })
```

This assumes that the `onItemClick` function is defined in ItemList parent, and is being passed in as a prop.

Comment: The react dev tools shows the event is bind (just like in some other cases I tried), but it's actually not registered on the actual DOM. What could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: I'm noticing that in the ItemList render function, you are rendering `Item`, but your child component is actually called `ItemPoint`? Perhaps this is part of the issue? Edit: Just realized that @jpdelatorre has already asked this in another way.

Comment: No, I had changed the names in the code before, now changed to real code. Any more ideas?

Comment: Where is the `onAgendaPointClick ` function defined? Shouldn't this event be defined in `AgendaPointsList`? It seems that you are missing `onClick={this.props.onAgendaPointClick}` in your `AgendaPoint` component as well.